# Unable to load QML plugin: cannot protect module as it was never registered

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I am unable to load a qml file from C++:

```
QQmlComponent component(&engine, QUrl("qrc:/qml/Singletons.qml"));
```

At the top of this file we have

```
import My.Module 1.0
```

The error is (`component.errorString()`):

```
plugin cannot be loaded for module "My.Module": Cannot protect module My.Module 1 as it was never registered
```

`My.Module` is a plugin containing qml only. It has been successfully loaded using `QQmlEngine::importPlugin`. The qml components are in a qrc and are compiled. I don't register any types in the plugin itself. This worked for Qt 5.14.1 but doesn't work for Qt 5.15.0

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that I didn't register any types, in this case it turns out you need to call `qmlRegisterModule`:

```
void MyModulePlugin::registerTypes(const char *uri)
{
    Q_ASSERT(uri == QLatin1String("My.Module"));
    qmlRegisterModule(uri, 1, 0);
}
```

Comment: I did register types from the plugin and app which uses it starts normally from the command line, but fails with the complain from this question if I try to start it from Xcode.

Comment: Worst case you'll have to debug the qt code, that's what I ended up doing. A difference in cmdline <-> xcode points to e.g. a different working directory or different environment variables, maybe you could check those?